# How to show (on iscsi target) which initiators (if any) are active?

Tags: iscsi

An Ubuntu host is an iSCSI target using targetcli. Once configured how can I show on the *target host* which initiators are (if any) are active?

Answer (score 1):

You can use (tested in Ubuntu 18.04):

```
targetcli sessions detail
```

It will come out as :

```
alias:  sid: 8 type: Normal session-state: LOGGED_IN
   name: iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:srvr01 (NOT AUTHENTICATED)
   mapped-lun: 0 backstore: block/storage01 mode: rw
   address: 10.0.0.11 (TCP)  cid: 1 connection-state: LOGGED_IN
alias:  sid: 9 type: Normal session-state: LOGGED_IN
   name: iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:srvr02 (NOT AUTHENTICATED)
   mapped-lun: 0 backstore: block/storage01 mode: rw
   address: 10.0.0.12 (TCP)  cid: 1 connection-state: LOGGED_IN
alias:  sid: 10 type: Normal session-state: LOGGED_IN
   name: iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:srvr03 (NOT AUTHENTICATED)
   mapped-lun: 0 backstore: block/storage01 mode: rw
   address: 10.0.0.13 (TCP)  cid: 1 connection-state: LOGGED_IN
```